# Несколько приложений в одном docker-контейнере

Tags: docker

Добрый день.

Возможно-ли создать контейнер на основе ubuntu и установить в нем несколько приложений (Jenkins, GitLab, Confluence + сопутствующий софт(java, ruby, apache, postgreSQL))?

Comment: да, это возможно.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что прямой ответ на него — «да/нет», а на подразумеваемый вопрос («как сделать то, про что я спрашиваю?») невозможно дать краткий исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: подразумеваемый вопрос - "если это возможно - ткните носом во внятное руководство, где написано как это сделать правильно"

Comment: например, можно начать с [get started with docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/)